# Running Javascript with Blazor side by side

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to use Bootstrap html javascript based template "Metronic" on a new Blazor project but they don't play together

when i remove this

```
    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

line from the _Host.chstml Page it the templates works fine, but when i add it the Blazor works fine but none of the template functions

what i want to achieve is finding a way to run both together, or also if i can call "import" entire javascript file from another javascript function

Comment: it seems to me that you are adding a "server" version of Blazor isn't there any blazor.client.js ? Or maybe you can 'change' the scope of your blazor javascript file.

Comment: Yes, its a "server" version which is relays on SignalR as client version won't be released in the next version, only the server-side version

Comment: Blazor team on git hub responded with 
"To avoid this problem, you should use jQuery's on method (passing a selector) instead of .click"

will i find any online template that fully use selectors?

Comment: @AhmedVolcano did you ever figure this out? I'm using JS interop for a a couple things but I'm having trouble with the aside menu toggle.

Comment: @mjung i have posted that on Blazor github page, and they told me that its not supported for server-side Blazor, and it should be working fine with client-side one

Comment: Did you have success implementing the theme with Blazor server side?

Comment: Actually still now it's not supported so my choice went to using new frameworks like MatBlazor, BlazorStrap, or Ant Design @BugLover